# Ruby on Rails - Facebook Authentication with REST backend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, rest, architecture

I am building a javascript front-end and a Rails REST API backend. Users can only login using Facebook. What is the best architecture for something like this? I am a Rails and REST newbie but here's what I'm thinking so far:

1. Login on the client using the FB javascript library
2. Send a request to /users/current. Include the FB token in the request. (Is this URL restful?)
3. On the server

   - If the token is valid, fetch the users info and transmit the JSON back (id, pic, name, etc)
   - If the token is invalid, transmit an error back

Could someone please point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct, I'm actually developing an application using same concept but through Google login.

What you are looking for is OAuth 2.0 for Facebook or OpenID if you plan to incorporate federated login.

So yeah, basically what you said is correct. You get the authorization token from the client, send request to the server which you should have a authentication method that checks for the validity of the token by sending a GET request for user info to facebook with that token. After you get the response, you should return the information in JSON or an error depending on the data you get back from the GET request.

[Facebook OAuth 2.0](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/)

That should point you in the right direction. Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 1):

@Leo has given you one direction of approach.

Another way is to use Devise.

1. Configure Devise to be Token Authenticatable.
   Steps here: http://matteomelani.wordpress.com/2011/10/17/authentication-for-mobile-devices/
2. Set `config.skip_session_storage = [:token_auth]` in initializers/devise.rb so that session is not stored and you have to send token id every time
3. Define a function as below. This function validates if the FB access token you send is correct and if it corresponds to the FB id. We have to use this function in places where valid_password is called, as we don't ve have a password created by user in our database. But we have to get it verified from Facebook.

   ```
   def self.valid_password_custom?(password, fbid)
     uri = URI.parse("https://graph.facebook.com/me")
     fb_params = {"access_token"=>password}
     http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
     http.use_ssl = true
     request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.path)
     request.set_form_data( fb_params )
     request = Net::HTTP::Get.new( uri.path + "?" + request.body )
     response = http.request(request)
     json_response = JSON.parse(response.body)

     if json_response["id"] == fbid
       logger.debug("FB Access token is valid for the user")
       return true
     else
       logger.debug("FB Access token is not valid for the user. ID for access token is '#{fbid}'")
       return false
     end
   end
   ```
4. Once the above steps are set you ll get a token back from devise. You can use it to communicate with APIs